# How can I subscribe others to get email notifications from teamcity builds?

Tags: teamcity

We are a large group of developers, working on a project. We recently switched to `TeamCity` for managing the build process. I would like every developer to get a notification of the build success or failure. Since most of the developers are unfamiliar with `TeamCity`, and are super busy anyway, I'm concerned that asking them to subscribe to the build result may take a long time.

**My Question:** Is there a way to subscribe on the behalf of others to get build notifications via email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a group (`Administration - User Management - Groups`), assign users to the group and create a new notification rule (email, IDE notififications, Windows Tray - whatever you want) for the group (`Group detail - Notification rules`).